# select entries from database mysql in dropdown, python flask

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I want to select data from database table in MySQL. It is procedure in Python

```
@app.route('/formworkers.html')
def formworkers(): 
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur = cursor.execute("SELECT ID_worker, surname FROM workers")
return render_template('formworkers.html', workers0=cursor.fetchall())
```

And template in Jinja2

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block body %}
    {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="" method=post class=add-worker >
      <dl>
        <dt>Surname:
        <dd><select name="worker0">
        {% for ID_pats, surname in workers0 %}
        <option value="{{ ID_worker }}">{{ surname }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <dd><input type=submit value="Submit">
      </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the dropdown list does not contain data (for example [Ivanov, Petrov, Sidorov]) from the database, it contain values [surname, surname, surname]. Thank you.

Comment: could you add `{{workers0}}` in your template to check what is sent by the view ?

Comment: @PRMoureu, I write in template `<option value="{{ workers0.ID_pats }}">{{ workers0.surname }}</option>`, but dropdown list is empty, but have 3 empty elements

Comment: @PRMoureu, just write before `for` `{{workers0}}`?

Comment: just above the line `<dd><select name="worker0">`, only to see what it contains exactly

Comment: @PRMoureu, it output `({'ID_worker': 1L, 'surname': u'\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432'}, {'ID_worker': 2L, 'surname': u'\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432'}, {'ID_worker': 3L, 'surname': u'\u0421\u0438\u0434\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432'})`

Answer (score 2):

The query outputs a result as a list of dictionaries, so when you unpack it in the `for` loop, you get only a list of keys `"ID_worker"` and `"surname"` .

You can change the template like below [to access the values](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables) :

```
{% for worker in workers0 %}

<option value="{{ worker.ID_worker }}">{{ worker.surname }}</option>

{% endfor %}
```